# How can I use div tags more effectively on my page?

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have the following html:

```
 <body>           
   <div id="content">
      <div class="mainlogo">
         <div class="logo">
            <a href="http://somepage.com/"><img src="images/image.jpg" border="0"/></a>
         </div>
         <div class="content-name">
           <h1>Content One</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="compinfo">
         <h1>Information.....</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="frame">
         <div class="iframe">
            <iframe src="somecontent.html/"></iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body
```

And my css is as follows:

```
.mainlogo 
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo 
{
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 35px;
    top: 5px;
    float:right;
}

.nav
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
}

.nav a
{
    display: block;
    background: #c8c8c8;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Sans-Serif;
    font-size:large;
}

a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none; 
}

.nav a:hover
{
    background: green; 
}

/*h1
{
    font-size:70px
    color: #121b50;
    font-style:italic;
    /*margin: 10px 30px 18px -600px;
    font-family:"pt-sans-narrow", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-right: 50px;
}*/

h1{
    font-style: italic;
    /*margin: 5px -600px -50px 300px;*/
    font-family: "pt-sans-narrow", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    float:right;
}

a
{
  color:#0000FF;
}

.content-name h1
{
    text-align:right;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.iframe
{
    text-align:center;    
}

.frame
{
   padding-top: 5px; 
}   


#compinfo
{
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    text-align:left;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8em;  
}
```

When a page is loaded there is some extra gap between logo section with a text and  section.

What posibly can be wrong? How can I correct it so no gap appears between logo section and  section?

Thank you

Comment: It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?  Did you try inspecting the elements to see if they had any default styles applied to them?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with the answer: but use iFrames with care. With PHP, you can load pages in other pages without even having to reload the rest of the page. Most browser are even smart only to load the parts that change, assuming you use the same template on every page

Answer (score 1):

By default, heading tags have margins on them, try adding margin zero to your h1 tag. That could be causing the gap.

```
h1 {
margin: 0;
}
```